# Laravel 5.1 - Select all models with a number of pivots on many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have 2 models, **Clients** and **Actions**, with a Many To Many Relationship. In a pivot table "inter_clients_actions" I have the associations between **Clients** and **Actions** plus a boolean field called *attended*.

**Model client:**

```
public function actions(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Action', 'inter_clients_actions', 'id_client', 'id_action')->withPivot('attended');
    }
```

**Action Model:**

```
public function clients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client', 'inter_clients_actions', 'id_action', 'id_client')->withPivot('attended');
  }
```

**inter_clients_actions pivot table:**

```
id_client
id_action
attended
```

Now I have to obtain each client and the number of actions attended for selecting the clients with no actions and clients with less than 5 actions.

I know I can select the clients with attended actions with the command:

```
$aux_clients = Client::whereHas('actions', function($query){
    $query->where('attended', true);
});
```

But it gives me no number of actions. Is there a command to obtain the number of attended actions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the trick:

```
$aux_clients = Client::whereHas('actions', function($query){
    $query->where('attended', true);
}, '<', 5);
```

You request < 5, thus that's 'including no actions'.